# Reduce string to shortest

Tags: java, string, reduce

I am trying to reduce a string to shortest one. In `for` loop, I'm checking all chars with `str2.charAt( i ) == str2.charAt( i + 1 )` and creating new string with `str2 = str2.substring ( 0 , i ) + str2.substring ( i + 2 );` then `i=0` to check new string. However, I cannot do that for upper and lower case both. I mean as example,

**Input:** `aabcddef`

**Output:** `bcef`

is okey but,

**Input:** `AabcddeFf`

**Output:** `AabceFf`

I need to get output: `bce` in this situation. I couldn't use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method. How I can fix it?

Comment: Convert the char to uppercase and then compare them `Character.toUpperCase(character)`.

Comment: `Character.toUpperCase(str2.charAt(i)) == Character.toUpperCase(str2.charAt(i + 1))`

Comment: Please always share the code )

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When comparing like you do, a `A` is not equals to a `a`, you may check equality with ignoring the case, you can do it by setting both to uppercase

```
if (Character.toUpperCase(str2.charAt(i)) == Character.toUpperCase(str2.charAt(i + 1))) {
    str2 = str2.substring(0, i) + str2.substring(i + 2);
    i = 0;
}
```

Comment: @buyufix You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and vote up if you want